# how to change point style legend to diamond in chart js

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I want to change the point style of my legend to diamond but don't know how to do it. I am attaching the jsfiddle file in the comment.

Comment: here's the js fiddle link   https://jsfiddle.net/t0nsdzh5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pointStyle` should be updated to `rectRot` instead of `rect`. Please read more about it [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.5.0/configuration/elements.html#point-styles)

Updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7uLtg6n5/)

Edit: For adding a `'%'` sign at the end of each tooltip label, add a tooltip callback as shown in the following [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c583ubdL/)

Comment: one more thing I want to add % symbol at the end of each label when we hover and tooltip shows.   link : https://jsfiddle.net/3dsp20fx/

Comment: @Adeel I have updated my answer to reflect the required modifications.